# Converting physical address to logical

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, paging, memory-allocation

In 8-bit address space there are 16 pages and the page table stores:

*68792EA51BD3CF04* (hex)

The physical address is *39h*, what is the corresponding logical address?

---

I have literally no idea what to do, tried to look on different sites and work with formulas but nothing seems to work. I don't think it was ever covered on the lectures but it might show up at the exam.

I'd appreciate any form of help, thank you and sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Without any inlkling of the format of the page table, it is anybody's guess.

Comment: Does it mean that the question might be badly worded or have not enough data?

Comment: What is that 68792EA51BD3CF04 ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a linking **page table** which links the page number (logical address) to the frame number (physical address) and vice versa.